# Pull data without altering the item sequence in the reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to lookup values listed in a temp table:

So let us say:

```
Create Table #mylist
(
eserial nvarchar(35) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS,
refdate datetime
)

Insert Into #mylist (eserial, refdate) Values ('A', '2015-09-15')
Insert Into #mylist (eserial, refdate) Values ('B', '2015-09-14')
Insert Into #mylist (eserial, refdate) Values ('C', '2015-09-13')
Insert Into #mylist (eserial, refdate) Values ('D', '2015-09-12')
```

I need the result to be the `Top 1` date less than the reference date.
And should be returned in the same sequence as is in the temporary table.

What I tried:

```
Select
    lst.eserial,
    lst.refdate,
    app.CREATEDDATETIME,
From #mylist lst
Outer Apply 
    (Select Top 1 rec.CREATEDDATETIME, rec.ESERIAL, rec.ITEMID
     From TableSource rec
     Where lst.eserial=rec.ESERIAL And rec.CREATEDDATETIME<lst.refdate
     Order By rec.CREATEDDATETIME Desc
    ) As app
```

This works but it is slow. Also, if the number of rows are increased, it does not consistently preserve the sequence of `eserial`. I need the query to preserve the order I put it in the temporary table.

Again my expected output is simply:

[image]

Where `eserial` is the same sequence as the temp table and `CREATEDDATETIME` is the maximum date less than the reference date. More like a conditional `Vlookup` if you know Excel.

Comment: Honestly, I would've expected the OUTER APPLY method would work the best in a general case.  Are you not creating any indexes on your temp table?  Can you specify `eserial` as a `PRIMARY KEY` in your create?

Comment: @BaconBits I tried specifying it as Primary Key but the same result. The second code is faster almost 10x.

Comment: Have you tried with an index on ESERIAL, CREATEDDATETIME desc include(ITEMID) where AREAID='home'

Comment: I'd recommend you to edit the question and leave only relevant bits in your question. I understand you've been rewriting your query and the question evolved. Leave only the latest variant, which is temp table having two columns, query has `outer apply` and doesn't use `AREAID='home'`. (This is how I understood it, I may be wrong, that's why I ask you to clean it up.) The way it is now is rather confusing.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Edited.

Comment: @L42, your problem would become much clearer if in your sample data you showed that you insert `B`, then `A`, then `C`, then `D` and then show expected result again in this order (`B, A, C, D`). With this example it would be clear that you want to preserve the order (sequence in your terms) of rows as they were inserted into the table, **not** the order of values in the `eserial` column.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Ok got it. I didn't occur to me that I have to implicitly state it that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you mean by

> maintain the sequence of the items in the temporary table

, but if you want to get result ordered by `eserial`, then you have to add `ORDER BY eserial` to your query. Without `ORDER BY` the resulting rows can be returned in any order. This applies to any method that you choose.

So, taking your last query as a basis, it will look like this:

```
Select
    lst.eserial
    ,lst.refdate
    ,app.CREATEDDATETIME
From
    #mylist lst
    Outer Apply
    (
        Select Top 1 rec.CREATEDDATETIME
        From TableSource rec
        Where lst.eserial=rec.ESERIAL And rec.CREATEDDATETIME<lst.refdate
        Order By rec.CREATEDDATETIME Desc
    ) As app
ORDER BY lst.eserial;
```

To make it work fast and efficiently add an index to `TableSource` on `(ESERIAL, CREATEDDATETIME)`. Order of columns in the index is important.

It is also important to know if there are any other columns that you use in `OUTER APPLY` query and how you use them. You mentioned column `AREAID` in the first variant in the question, but not in the last variant. If you do have more columns, then clearly show how you intend to use them, because the correct index would depend on it. The index on `(ESERIAL, CREATEDDATETIME)` is enough for the query I wrote above, but if you have more columns a different index may be required.

It would also help optimizer if you defined your temp table with a `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
Create Table #mylist
(
    eserial nvarchar(35) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS PRIMARY KEY,
    refdate datetime
)
```

Primary key would create a unique clustered index.

One more important note. What is the type and collation of columns `ESERIAL` and `CREATEDDATETIME` in the main `TableSource` table? Make sure that types and collation of columns in your temp table matches the main `TableSource` table. If the type is different (`varchar` vs. `nvarchar` or `datetime` vs. `date`) or collation is different index may not be used => it will be slow.

**Edit**

You use the phrase "same sequence as the temp table" several times in the question, but it is not really clear what you mean by it. Your sample data doesn't help to resolve the ambiguity. The column name `eserial` also adds to the confusion. I can see two possible meanings:

1. Return rows from temp table ordered by values in `eserial` column.
2. Return rows from temp table in the same order as they were inserted.

My original answer implies (1): it returns rows from temp table ordered by values in `eserial` column.

If you want to preserve the order of rows as they were inserted into the table, you need to explicitly remember this order somehow. The easiest method is to add an `IDENTITY` column to the temp table and later order by this column. Like this:

```
Create Table #mylist
(
    ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    eserial nvarchar(35) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS,
    refdate datetime
)
```

And in the final query use `ORDER BY lst.ID`.

Comment: `Without ORDER BY the resulting rows can be returned in any order. This applies to any method that you choose` So does this mean that what I want cannot be achieved? How I put it in the temp table is the order I want it returned.

Comment: This is not a true technical problem, it's a conceptual problem. i.e. this isn't a problem for 99% of SQL Server developers. It seems you already solved your problem by adding a field to the table to indicate order, and that is what you must do.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid So that is the only way. Like what Eric posted. Adding another field which will uniquely preserve the sequence.

Comment: Yes. There is no 'logical' sequence till you add a field which contains that information.

Comment: A _clustered index_ ensures that data is _logically_ ordered in that way but that's purely for performance reasons and is still no guarantee that data will come back in that order without an `ORDER BY`

Comment: @L42, I updated the answer. One of the fundamental principles in relational databases is that tables are unordered sets of rows. If you need to get result in a particular order, use `ORDER BY`. There is no other way. Indexes may help to run the query faster, they may help if sorting is needed, but final order of the result is guaranteed only if you use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: So yeah, @Nick.McDermaid is right that only way to get it done is how I did it in the first post. Ok that settles it. No way around it then. And simplest answer would be to add identity to it.

Comment: @L42, you effectively have two questions. One relates to order of rows and getting correct results. It seems that using `OUTER APPLY` together with `IDENTITY` column and `ORDER BY ID` solves it. Second question is how to make the query run fast. This is where appropriate index(es) are required. The index on `(ESERIAL, CREATEDDATETIME)` that I suggested should be enough.

Comment: Why not include `ID` on the index?

Comment: Index should be on `TableSource` table.

Answer (score 3):

That's easy using identity. Query without `Order` is not guarantee to have order in SQL server.

```
Create Table #mylist
(
    seqId int identity(1,1),
    eserial nvarchar(35) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS,
    refdate datetime
)
```

Use the table freely and put `Order By seqId` at the end of your query

**Edit**

Use `MAX()` instead of `TOP 1` with order if you have no cluster index on `ESERIAL`, `CREATEDDATETIME` on the TableSource

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420643/1287352

```
Select
    lst.eserial,
    lst.refdate,
    app.CREATEDDATETIME,
From #mylist lst
Outer Apply 
    (
        Select MAX(rec.CREATEDDATETIME), rec.ESERIAL, rec.ITEMID
        From TableSource rec
        Where lst.eserial = rec.ESERIAL And rec.CREATEDDATETIME < lst.refdate
        GROUP BY rec.ESERIAL, rec.ITEMID
    ) As app
ORDER BY lst.seqId
```

Comment: This is similar to the approach I used before I edit the question which was requested by @VladimirBaranov, except you use `Identity`. But same logic.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the performance issue is due to indexing.  Try adding the indexes below, removing `UNIQUE` if the keys are not unique.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON #mylist (eserial, refdate);
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON TableSource (eserial, CREATEDDATETIME);
```