# Finding a min value to use in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

A colleague wrote this piece of SQL (SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT 
    a.account_id
   ,(SELECT SUM(e.amount)
     FROM event e 
     WHERE e.event_type_id <> 47 
     AND e.master_comm_id = (SELECT c.comm_id 
                             FROM comm c
                             WHERE c.item_id = a.item_id
                             AND c.comp_type_id = 20 
                             AND c.comm_type_id = 485)) 
FROM account a
```

However, there are cases where there are multiple master_comm_ids against an event, and so the query fails (*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*). I only want the first master_comm_id, ie. the MIN one.

I have looked at various similar questions and attempted various things to achieve this (using MIN or ROW_NUMBER and rearranging the query to use joins etc) but I must be missing something obvious as everything has either resulted in SQL errors or the wrong data or not fixed the issue.

Can anyone help me just find the min master_comm_id to then use in the subquery?

Comment: Please post table structures and some sample data.

Comment: The best way to get useful advice here is to include your table structures, some minimal sample data that demonstrates the issue, and your expected outcome. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why wouldn't `ORDERBY` work?

Comment: Do you have an actual reason for "min" of the id or is that just an attempt to make it a single value?

Comment: Please show your attempt to use min(), and explain what went wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top 1 works, but only if the data is ordered (per below SO)

You mentioned you tried MIN, but where?  This may work (you are very close):

```
SELECT 
    a.account_id
   ,(SELECT SUM(e.amount)
     FROM event e 
     WHERE e.event_type_id <> 47 
     AND e.master_comm_id = (SELECT **MIN**(c.comm_id)
                             FROM comm c
                             WHERE c.item_id = a.item_id
                             AND c.comp_type_id = 20 
                             AND c.comm_type_id = 485)) 
FROM account
```

[MAX vs Top 1 - which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198274/max-vs-top-1-which-is-better)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. Since I don't have sample data, I cannot check, but it looks obvious - select only top 1, while the select list is ordered by the ID ascending...

```
SELECT 
    a.account_id
   ,(SELECT SUM(e.amount)
     FROM event e 
     WHERE e.event_type_id <> 47 
     AND e.master_comm_id = (SELECT top 1 c.comm_id 
                             FROM comm c
                             WHERE c.item_id = a.item_id
                             AND c.comp_type_id = 20 
                             AND c.comm_type_id = 485
                             ORDER BY C.COMM_ID ASC)) 
FROM account a
```

Answer (score 2):

The "normal" solution is to use `IN` or `= ANY`:

```
SELECT a.account_id,
       (SELECT SUM(e.amount)
        FROM event e 
        WHERE e.event_type_id <> 47 AND
              e.master_comm_id IN (SELECT c.comm_id 
                                   FROM comm c
                                   WHERE c.item_id = a.item_id AND
                                         c.comp_type_id = 20 AND
                                         c.comm_type_id = 485
                                  )
       ) as sumamount 
FROM account a;
```

There are other alternatives, such as an explicit `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

I actually notice that the subquery does not have a correlation clause.  Without one, it will always returns the same value.  It is clearer to put such queries in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT a.account_id, e.sumamount 
FROM account a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(e.amount) as sumamount
      FROM event e 
      WHERE e.event_type_id <> 47 AND
            e.master_comm_id IN (SELECT c.comm_id 
                                 FROM comm c
                                 WHERE c.item_id = a.item_id AND
                                       c.comp_type_id = 20 AND
                                       c.comm_type_id = 485
                                )
     ) e;
```

Some databases will execute the subquery in the `SELECT` for every row.  SQL Server is probably smart enough to optimize that away.  But, putting it in the `FROM` clause guarantees that it is executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.account_id,
        oa.[amount] 
FROM    account a
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  SUM(e.amount) [amount]
            FROM    event e 
            WHERE   e.event_type_id <> 47 
                    AND EXISTS (
                        SELECT  1 
                        FROM    comm c
                        WHERE   e.master_comm_id = c.comm_id
                                AND c.item_id = a.item_id
                                AND c.comp_type_id IN (20, 485)
                    )
        ) oa
```

if what you're saying about `I only want the first master_comm_id, ie. the MIN one.` means you only want the sum from the `min(master_comm_id)` then you can try something like this.

```
SELECT  a.account_id,
        oa.[amount] 
FROM    account a
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  MIN(e.master_comm_id) master_comm_id
            FROM    event e
            WHERE   e.event_type_id <> 47
                    AND EXISTS (
                        SELECT  1 
                        FROM    comm c
                        WHERE   e.master_comm_id = c.comm_id
                                AND c.item_id = a.item_id
                                AND c.comp_type_id IN (20, 485)
                    )
        ) mmci
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  SUM(e.amount) [amount]
            FROM    event e
            WHERE   e.master_comm_id = mmci.master_comm_id
                    AND e.event_type_id <> 47
        ) oa
```